# Server 2008 R2 failing DCDIAG - not advertising as a time server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, active-directory

When I first started working on this issue the only test that was failing was it not advertising as a time server now the following is coming up:

```
 Warning: LEX-DC01 is not advertising as a time server.
 ......................... LEX-DC01 failed test Advertising
 Error NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS doesn't have
    Replicating Directory Changes In Filtered Set
 access rights for the naming context:
 DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=ja,DC=com
 Error NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS doesn't have
    Replicating Directory Changes In Filtered Set
 access rights for the naming context:
 DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=ja,DC=com
```

I have tried:

Check the `announceflags` registry setting from

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config
annd verify that it is set to 10 in decimal (0x0000000A), then use w32tm /config /update
```

I have also tried:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update
```

then:

```
net stop w32time 
net start w32time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up demoting and promoting the DC in hopes of fixing the issue but it came right back. At this point time wise it might just be easier to rebuild the server. If I end up finding the fix I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `announceflags` registry setting from

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config
```

annd verify that it is set to 10 in decimal (0x0000000A), then use `w32tm /config /update`

See [Windows Time Service Tools and Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28WS.10%29.aspx#w2k3tr_times_tools_uhlp)

Also try running

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update
```

then:

```
net stop w32time 
net start w32time
```

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried but no luck :(

Comment: You can propbably eliminate the second error by running adprep /rodcprep, but the time error is troubling.  Can you add the entries from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config
 to your question.  I have also updated my answer.  If there is anything else you have tried please add that to your question

Comment: I have tried a few different variations of w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update besides that I have just been trying every thing I could find from google

Comment: can you add your HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config registry entries?

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same issue at one of my Domain controller.I fixed this issue by registering the `w32tm` for that domain controller.

Steps which I followed to resolve the issuse:

1. `w32tm /unregister` then Reboot your DC.
2. `w32tm /register` again Reboot your DC.
3. `w32tm /config /update`